# Dense set in an open set

Tags: general-topology

I try to prove the following proposition: Let $X$ a topological space, $A,B \subset X$ where $B$ is open. $A$ is dense in $B$ if and only if $\bar{A} \supset B$ (where $\bar{A}$ is the closure of $A$).

To clarify, the definition used in my textbook states that:

- $A \subset X$ is dense in $X$ if $\bar{A} = X$.
- Given $A,B \subset X$, we say that $A$ is dense in $B$ if $A \cap B$ is dense in the subspace $B$.

I had some difficulties proving this proposition, and would appreciate some help.

Comment: There are several equivalent definitions of *dense in a set*; which is yours?

Comment: If $A$ is dense in $B$ then $\overline{A} = B$ thus $B\subset\overline{A}$

Comment: I updated the question with my definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the definitions that you’re using, you’re being asked to show that $\operatorname{cl}_B(A\cap B)=B$ (i.e., $A$ is dense in the subspace $B$) iff $\operatorname{cl}A\supseteq B$. (Here $\operatorname{cl}_B$ is the closure in the subspace $B$, while $\operatorname{cl}$ is the closure in the space $X$.) Thus, you have to show two things:

- if $\operatorname{cl}A\supseteq B$, then $\operatorname{cl}_B(A\cap B)=B$; and
- if $\operatorname{cl}_B(A\cap B)=B$, then $\operatorname{cl}A\supseteq B$.

The second of these is pretty straightforward and does not use the fact that $B$ is open in $X$. If $\operatorname{cl}_B(A\cap B)=B$, then every point of $B$ is a limit point of $A\cap B$, and from there it’s a small step to the desired conclusion.

For the first one you’ll need to use the fact that $B$ is open. Your hypothesis tells you that every point of $B$ is a limit point of $A$, and you’ll need to show that this actually ensures that every point of $B$ is a limit point of $A\cap B$.

Comment: Hi. Today I tried to prove this proposition again. I had a probelm in the first thing I need to prove you mentioned above: if $\operatorname{cl} A \supseteq B$, then $\operatorname{cl}_B(A \cap B) = B$. My problem was in the proof of the $\subseteq$ inclusion. I take $x \in \operatorname{cl}_B(A \cap B)$, meaning there is a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $x_n \to x$. But why we have $x \in B$?

Comment: *... a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $A \cap B$ ...

Comment: Or maybe it's true because the closure in taken in the subspace topology of $B$, and hence $x$ is automatically in $B$? I think I'm a little bit confused.